# Is there a concise argument for why this group operation is associative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Given disjoint groups $(G,\cdot)$ and $(H,\ast)$ and an isomorphism $f:G\to H$, I've been able to show that the binary operation $\diamond$ on $G\cup H$ defined by

$a\diamond b = a\cdot b$ if $a,b \in G$

$a\diamond b = f^{-1}(a)\cdot f^{-1}(b)$ if $a,b \in H$

$a\diamond b = f(a)\ast b$ if $a\in G, b\in H$

$a\diamond b = a\ast f(b)$ if $a\in H, b\in G$

is a group operation on $G\cup H$. However, my argument that $\diamond$ is associative amounts to checking eight cases, and is therefore very tedious. I'm wondering if there's a simpler, more concise proof that $(a\diamond b)\diamond c= a\diamond(b\diamond c)$ for all $a,b,c\in G\cup H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this defined operation we have $G\cup H\simeq G\times C_2$, where $C_2$ is the group of order $2$. Since $G\times C_2$ is a group, so is $G\cup H$.

The isomorphism $\varphi:G\times \{0,1\}\to G\cup H$ can be defined by $\varphi(g,0)=g,\quad \varphi(g,1)=f(g).$ The verification that this is indeed an isomorphism is easy.

Comment: Could you please provide the morphism?

Comment: @ xavierm02, I added it to my post, please have a look.

Comment: For some reason, I thought that the result was in the set of the second argument. So I thought you had to use a monoid instead of $C_2$ with the operation defined as right-absorbant. Anyway, +1

Comment: All right, cheers:)